# Analyzing runtime of function for list and stack structure

Tags: python, algorithm, runtime

I wrote a pesudocode, but I'm having trouble figuring out its runtime.

```
Algorithm Reverse(A, N ):
Input: A list and number of items in the list
Output: A list that is in reverse order of original list
Stack S
For item in the list A:
  V ← A.pop(0)
  S.push(V)
For item in the stack S
  X ← S.pop()
  A.append(X)
return A
```

Since all operations are done with O(1) #pop, push, pop, append at the end of the list, is this algorithm simply just be O(n) for the runtime?

Comment: Yes, O(n) is correct, provided that `pop(0)`, `push`, `pop()`, and `append` are O(1).

Comment: @user3386109 thank you, 4O(n)  and we are supposed to get rid of constant C and therefore its O(n), I think I understand now just being uncertain for my answer! Appreciate the help